# How to check if a User is online?

Tags: botframework

If I have an user address and channel-name I can send message to that user. Before sending a message I wish to know if that user is online.

Does the ping message help or is there some other way ?

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework currently does not support determining if a user is actively on-line

Comment: Is there now a way to determine if user is actively online?

Comment: This question is 2 years and 3 months old now. Has this functionality been added in the meantime?